# Streamlit bar chart with different color for each label

Tags: python, plot, vega-lite, streamlit

I have a DataFrame that contains two columns:

- Nucleotide (ordinal, only unique values)
- Similarities (quantative, count of specific Nucleotide)

I want to plot an **interactive** bar chart using Streamlit, where each Nucleotide will have different color, like on the example below:

[image: Example bar chart]

I know how to do it using matplotlib or seaborn, but these figures are not interactive.
Also my approach using vega-lite does not work, because the 'c' argument for the colormap cannot refer to the axis being already used on the plot.

```
st.vega_lite_chart(df, {
     'mark': {'type': 'bar', 'tooltip': True},
     'encoding': {
         'x': {'field': 'Nucleotide', 'type': 'ordinal'},
         'y': {'field': 'Similarities', 'type': 'quantitative'},
         'color': {'field': 'Nucleotide', 'type': 'ordinal'},
     },
 })
```

Do you maybe have some other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Altair is a great choice here in my view. It comes out of the box with streamlit and creates very nice looking and interactive charts. Bascially you have to create a Chart object, pass in the data that you want to plot, and use the column names for things like x,y or color.
For your example, the code would read like

```py
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

chart = (
    alt.Chart(data)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        alt.X("Nucleotide:O"),
        alt.Y("Similarities"),
        alt.Color("Nucleotide:O"),
        alt.Tooltip(["Nucleotide", "Similarities"]),
    )
    .interactive()
)
st.altair_chart(chart)
```

assuming your dataframe is called data and the columns are called "Nucleotide" and "Similarities".
This would be a very basic bar chart that you can zoom in and hover over to see a tooltip.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask you, what does the trailing '0' mean in 'Nucleotide:0'?

Comment: This tell altair that the data is ordinal. This in some cases affects the way altair splits your data. Look at https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types for all available encodings

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Do you maybe know how to insert altair graph to excel spreadsheet, without saving it locally?